# Dynamic Linq query on Datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I want to make the following query dynamic.

```
var t = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()  
orderby r.Field< int >("id") ascending
select r;

void query(string sorttype,string sortorder)
```

Is it possbile to change the order by part so that those paramater will come from parameters of a function like
sorttype for id in here and sortorder for ascending.

Answer (score 0):

I think this ought to do it:

```
IEnumerable query<sorttype>(DataTable dt, string sortorder) {
    return dt.GetList().OrderBy(row => row.Field<sorttype>(sortorder));
}
```

Note that sorttype is a generic type parameter, not a string.

Comment: @hrrrr: you're correct, I've added a call to GetList() that should address this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338495.aspx